# Get value from radio button and add in url

Tags: jquery, url, radio-button

I have a list with radio button.When user checked the radio,it take the value of radio button and add it in the url.How can I complete this function? Following is my simple code. But it doesn't work.Help me,plz.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    var val = $(':radio[name=rdo_1]:checked').val();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        document.location.href = 'http://localhost/test/val1.html';

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where/how do you want to place the 'val' within the url?

Comment: Actually,I want to get product id from radio button and add it to my url.I set product id as radio button value.

Answer (score 1):

You can send params like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    var val = $(':radio[name=rdo_1]:checked').val();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        document.location.href = 'http://localhost/test/val1.html?radio_button_value='+val

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="submit"/>` enclosed with `<form method="get"> </form>`

Example would be like below.

But don't forget to add name fields

```
<form action="http://localhost/test/val1.html?" method="get" name="f">
    <input type="text" name="user" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />
    <input type="submit" class="login_button" value="LOGIN">
</form>
```

It's better since you don't use javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function($){
      $('#button').click(function(){
          var val = $(':radio[name=rdo_1]:checked').val(); 
          document.location.href = 'http://localhost/test/val1.html?radio='+val; 
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('input[@name="NAME"]:checked').val();
```

javascript:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('NAME');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
if (radios[i].checked) {
    alert(radios[i].value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the var assignment in the button click handler. If you don't do this, it will be assigned upon load, and any changes will not affect the function.

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var val = $(':radio[name=rdo_1]:checked').val();
        document.location.href = 'http://localhost/test/val1.html?radio_button_value=' + val
    });
});
```

Note: I also used the shorthand version of document ready.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('#button').click(function(){
        var val = $('input[type=radio][name=rdo_1]:checked').val();
        var url="http://localhost/test/"+val+".html";
        window.location.href = url;

    });
});
</script>
```